# Minikube to Object Storage Connection timed out Error with Spark Test

Tags: apache-spark, minikube

Having some issues with getting my local minikube docker vm to connect to an object storage resource in ibm cloud from my local machine. Everything works fine when exec'ing the image from my local machine with docker only. I feel like I'm just missing some network configuration in my minikube settings that would allow the vm to make an outside connection to my buckets. As soon as it gets to the part where it needs to read a file I get the following error.

```
com.ibm.stocator.thirdparty.cos.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to iam.cloud.ibm.com:443 failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Thank you @PjoterS for the feedback. Also to note that I'm only trying to run a one-time development test. So based on the feedback, what is the simplest way to expose my pod? My current process is installing spark-operator which creates a spark-operator pod in the spark-operator namespace. Afterwards I merely run the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: "<myapp>"
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "<path-to-image>"
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  mainClass: <class>
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///<path-to-jar>"
  driver:
    cores: 2
    memory: 5G
  executor:
    cores: 2
    instances: 5
    memory: 10G
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. You are using Minikube on IBM cloud or you want to connect from your minikube cluster to some resources on cloud? You need to elaborate what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I meant connecting to a resource in ibm cloud from my local minikube cluster. Not using minikube on IBM.

Comment: How did you expose your resources? Are you using LoadBalancer, NodePort or Ingress? Could you provide YAML configs?

Comment: that's precisely the part I think I'm missing which I was unsure how to configure. the documentation says to create a deployment and then expse the Pod as a Kubernetes Service ie. `--type=LoadBalancer`. But my application isn't a webserver of any kind and is just a simple spark operator helm installation with a very minimal yaml pointing to my image and `mainApplicationFile`. Am i supposed to be creating a service to expose my pod? does that require creating a deployment followed by a `kubectl expose` for my spark to object storage test?

Comment: To reach resources outside cluster, you MUST expose it. Type is like how you would like to reach your cluster. If chose LoadBalancer it would create LB with external IP which can be reached. If you will use NodePort you would reach it using <MachineIP>:<NodePort>, or you can also think about Ingress. Many depends on your need and pricing. You can find details in [cods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/). You can expose pod but its more recommended to exose deployment as it will take care to keep your app alive (can restart pod if it will crash).

Comment: If you have issue with your YAMLs you can post what you have here and it can be modified by community if it will need.